# Task class can't get the right value

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

In a For iteration, I put a Task in it. And each task runs its own job. Codes are as below:

```
 List<Task> lst_tsk = new List<Task>();
            List<int> lst_item = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
            foreach (var item in lst_item)
            {
                Task tsk = new Task(() =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item);
                });
                lst_tsk.Add(tsk);
                tsk.Start();
            }

            foreach (var t in lst_tsk)
            {
                if (t.IsCompleted == false)
                    t.Wait();
            }
```

I expect that it prints the 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.
But it works and breaks my thought.
the result is 10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10.

So how to edit the code to make things right?

Comment: Works for me. It prints out all the numbers in the random order.

Comment: If I debug it, not run it, it get the right value.

Comment: @Ondrej Janacek If you get the right value, that's because you use C#5 and roast_soul uses a previous version  We are taking the breaking change. In C# 5, the loop variable of a foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will close over a fresh copy of the variable each time

Comment: @AlexH Well, works for me even when buildid for .NET 4.0.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek - there's a difference between the target framework and the language compiler. If you're using the C# 5 compiler (VS 2012 or 13) then you get the new behaviour, no matter what framework you're targetting.

Comment: @Ondrej Janacek : I can reproduce the issue on VS 2010 / .net Framework 4.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a problem of closure and capture variable, the problem is completly explained in an [article by Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx)

To solve your problem, copy the item value at each iteration in a fresh variable :

```
 List<Task> lst_tsk = new List<Task>();
        List<int> lst_item = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        foreach (var item in lst_item)
        {
            var value = item;
            Task tsk = new Task(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            });
            lst_tsk.Add(tsk);
            tsk.Start();
        }

        foreach (var t in lst_tsk)
        {
            if (t.IsCompleted == false)
                t.Wait();
        }
```

Remark : this issue is fixed with C# 5.0 :

> In C# 5, the loop variable of a
>   foreach will be logically inside the loop, and therefore closures will
>   close over a fresh copy of the variable each time